# Script that outputs the total number of lines in all the text files that are passed as arguments

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

So I'm working on a script that will accept arguments that are text files, and should output the total number of lines in those files. 
For example, if I say

```
./myScript file1 file2 file3
```

it will print

```
10 total
```

(let us assume that the sum of all the lines from those three files is 10).

I know how to go over all the arguments. 
I also know that, to get the number of lines in a file, I would say:

```
wc -l < fileName
```

However, how can I make that into an "int" that I can add to some sort of cumulative sum?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish your goal simply by using `cat` and a pipeline:

```
cat "$@" | wc -l
```

If you really wanted to sum manually, you can do this with awk:

```
for f in "$@"; do 
    wc -l < "$f"
done | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print sum }'
```

Or if you really wanted to parse the last line of `wc`, removing the string "total":

```
wc -l "$@" | awk 'END { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me what your second code does? Not so familiar with `awk`

Comment: @haz it adds the first column of each line to the "sum" variable (which starts at 0) and then prints it after all lines have been read.

Answer (score 2):

Building on jordanm’s answer:

### 1. Pipe all the data through a single instance of `wc -l`

  ```
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
  then
      cat -- "$@" | wc -l
  else
      echo 0
  fi
  ```
  or
  ```
  cat -- /dev/null "$@" | wc -l
  ```

- Use `-- "$@"` to guard against filenames beginning with **`-`**.
- Avoid invoking `cat` with no arguments,
  as that will cause it to read the standard input.
- Note that `cat a_single_file | something`
  is the classic form of the dreaded [Useless Use of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat),
  but `cat one_or_more_file(s) | something`
  can be OK (although it’s still not ideal).

### 2. Rely on the fact that `wc` issues a “total” line

  ```
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
  then
      wc -l -- /dev/null "$@" | tail -1
  else
      echo 0 total
  fi
  ```
  or
  ```
  wc -l -- /dev/null /dev/null "$@" | tail -1
  ```

- Note that `wc` issues a `total` line
  only if it has at least two filename arguments.

### 3. Use `awk` without using `wc`

  ```
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
  then
      awk 'END {print NR}' -- "$@"
  else
      echo 0
  fi
  ```
  or
  ```
  awk 'END {print NR}' -- /dev/null "$@"
  ```

#### Warning:

The above commands will not all produce the same answer
if any of the files end with a character other than newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne\$= files...
```

Just hand `sed` as many filenames as you want in place of *`files...`* and, when it has read all of them, it will report the `=`line-number of the very `$`last in its input.